# Do Harry Potter stories mention other popular stories?

Tags: reference, harry-potter

In recent history Harry Potter stories have been mentioned in other popular story series such as Doctor Who and The Simpsons.

Do any of the Harry Potter movies mention any other book or TV serials?

Comment: Well, if you're asking about the *books*, you might need [SF&F](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/). This site is about the *films* only.

Comment: If you are after movies then it might work here, if only book then we might need to migrate it.

Answer (score 6):

While not a fictional series, there is a scene in Prisoner of Azkaban with a wizard doing wandless magic while reading ***A Brief History of Time*** by Stephen Hawking. The real life book is a treatise on quantum physics, and very well known. Introduction by Carl Sagan.

Comment: No, it's not particularly about quantum physics. The subtitle, From Big Bang to Black Holes, lists two concepts arising from classical cosmology.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recollect a mention of the fairy tales like "Cinderella" and few others in the Deathly Hallows when they are about to discuss The Tale of the Three Brothers when they visit Luna Lovegood's father at his home.